# Opening two FILE handles in read mode, on the same file, simultaneously

Tags: c, multithreading, stdio

I am writing a program that takes requests to read files and then send their contents via a TCP socket (an HTTP server). Clients are served simultaneously across multiple threads, and it has come to my attention that it is completely possible two clients will request the same file simultaneously.

My hope is that if Thread 1 calls `fopen(path,"rb");` and then Thread 2 also calls `fopen(path,"rb"); // Same path.` that, since both of these are opening the file at `path` in read mode, that given the path is valid both calls should succeed.

However I do have concern that after Thread 1 opens a `FILE*` that Thread 2's call to `fopen` will return `NULL` due to there already being an open file handle, and in the context of my HTTP server this would cause the client to wrongfully receive a `404 Not Found` error page, instead of the resource requested, which of course is not the desired result.

I'm sure there are ways to synchronize access or share file handles between these threads, but for sake of simplicity I'd like to be able to avoid implementing these more complex mechanisms.

On Windows with MinGW-w64 I find that this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    FILE* handle1 = fopen("testfile.txt","rb");
    FILE* handle2 = fopen("testfile.txt","rb");
    printf("%llX\n",handle1);
    printf("%llX\n",handle2);

    char buf [8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) buf[i] = 'X';
    fread(buf,1,8,handle1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) putchar(buf[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) buf[i] = 'X';
    fread(buf,1,8,handle2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) putchar(buf[i]);
    putchar('\n');
};
```

with `testfile.txt` containing `File Contents` produces the following output:

```
7FFE2439FA90
7FFE2439FAC0
File Con
File Con
```

...which is what I want it to do.

However I want to know whether this behavior is standard, or is only behaving as I want due to something about Windows or about the standard library implementation that my code is linking to.

If it is standard (or, at least common enough to be portable between Windows and Linux) behavior, I get to avoid making my code more convoluted than it needs to be. However of course, if it is not portable behavior, then I do need to figure something out.

---

TL;DR:

If "file.txt" is a valid path, then in the following code:

```
char* path = "file.txt";
FILE* file1 = fopen(path,"r");
FILE* file2 = fopen(path,"r");
```

across a variety of platforms,

- Will `file2 != file1` be guaranteed?
- Will `file2 != NULL` be guaranteed?
- Will `file1` still be valid?
- Will this have a danger of causing undefined behavior?
- Will this have a danger of causing a data race?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the same file for read-only access from multiple file-handles at once is not a problem; it will work reliably as expected.  Since no data in the file is being modified, and since all the transient state-data (e.g. buffered data, current-seek-position) is held in the `FILE` structure itself (and each thread has its own separate/private `FILE` structure), there is no race condition.

> Will file2 != file1 be guaranteed?

Yes.

> Will file2 != NULL be guaranteed?

Yes (assuming the file didn't get deleted or renamed between the two calls, of course :))

> Will file1 still be valid?

Yes.

> Will this have a danger of causing undefined behavior?

No.

> Will this have a danger of causing a data race?

No.

Comment: Thanks. I also noticed in my test program that I could actually open the file with one handle in "w" mode and another in "r" mode... Perhaps this indicates that as long as the file is being opened by the same **process** then it can be opened redundantly???

Comment: AFAIK under Linux/Unix style OSs there are no restrictions even for writable mode (although having one thread/process writing to a file while another thread reads or writes will likely cause some "interesting" behavior as the file's contents change --- probably not crashing, but I wouldn't rely on the data in the file being read back correctly in all cases).  Under Windows, IIRC having the file open in writable mode may cause other calls to fopen() to fail on that file since windows tries to prevent shared writable access to a file.

Comment: *Yes (assuming the file didn't get deleted or renamed between the two calls, of course :))* -- the process could have opened the maximum number of fds. It might still return `NULL`.

Comment: Makes sense about the "interesting" results, not really what I am trying to do in the first place anyway but I was just surprised seeing that I was allowed to open a write handle and also a read handle. I suppose the programmer is just trusted to do any necessary synchronization manually. As for the overall topic though, it sounds like the primary distinction is that a single **process** can open multiple handles to the same file, only when another **process** attempts to open the file during this time will those attempts be rejected?

Comment: @rsethc: multiple processes can open the same file simultaneously. If you think about it, this happens often since files have to be opened (by the loader) in order to execute them. Including dynamically-linked libraries.

Comment: @rsethc there are no special rules regarding processes -- anyone can open a file handle to any file they have permission to.  (For example, a Windows DLL is typically open for reading by dozens of processes at a time :) )

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I think I have just kind of always *assumed* that processes will prevent each other from opening the same file. I still suspect Windows will prevent processes from doing so if there is a write-mode handle open, but I suppose I really ought to go and test that hypothesis before I continue to operate under that assumption.

Comment: I think it will too -- as every Windows developer has sooner or later discovered, when he/she tries to rebuild the program while the previous test-build of that program is still running (and so the linker fails because the linker isn't allowed to open the .exe file for writing, while the previous test-build process still has it open for reading)

Comment: Did some testing and looks like several processes can all open read-mode handles simultaneously and successfully read from them. Throwing a write-mode handle into the mix does complicate things a lot, of course.

Comment: That about the linker failing is pretty accurate, happens to me all the time. Anyway I think this answers everything I was wondering, thanks a lot for the quick response!